# Using Sum function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table with following structure:

TestTable (ID INT, LoanID INT, Amount INT)

```
ID  LoanID  Amount
1   1        20
2   1        30
3   1        15
4   2        40
5   2        20
6   3        50
```

I want to calculate LoanAmounts with this scenario

```
ID  LoanID  Amount  Sum
1   1       20      20
2   1       30      50
3   1       15      65
4   2       40      40
5   2       20      60
6   3       50      50
```

What is the best way to get this Sum collumn (**Of course without cursor :)**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query to get the [running-totals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.LoanID, t.Amount,
       [Sum] = (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
                FROM TestTable t2
                WHERE t.LoanID=t2.LoanID
                AND t2.ID <= t.ID)
FROM TestTable t
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc108/4/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately SQL Server 2008 doesn't have a clean function to do a cumulative sum, so you need to add up all of the "previous" rows with the same `LoadID`:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  LoanID,  
  Amount,
  (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM TestTable t2 WHERE t2.LoanID = t.LoanID AND t2.ID <= t.ID) Sum
FROM TestTable t
```

Comment: It is not cumulative sum, look at OP output, Id 4 has 40 as sum and id 3 as 65

Comment: @RADAR It is cumulative _per `LoanID` group_.

Comment: @D Stanley, your query is good +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, LoanID, Amount, 
       (select sum(Amount)
        from TestTable A
        where  A.LoanID = B.LoanID and
               A.ID <= B.ID
       ) as Sum
from TestTable B;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using windowing function:

```
select *, sum(amount) over (partition by loanid order by id) as "sum" from testtable;
```

SQL server 2012:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc108/8

SQL server 2008:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc108/10

It works on SQL server 2012, but not on sql server 2008 using sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT b.id,a.LoanID,b.Amount,
           Sum(a.Amount) AS [Sum]
    FROM   #temp_table a
    JOIN   #temp_table b ON a.id <= b.id
                  AND a.LoanID = b.LoanID
    GROUP  BY b.id,a.LoanID,b.Amount
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```